# Exporting Shellbags, Jump Lists, and LNK files with PowerShell

Tags: beginner, windows, powershell

I'm new to PowerShell (started yesterday) and was wondering if there is a way of exporting Shell bags, Jump lists, and LNK files from the Reg to a local computer's desktop using PowerShell? I have tried a few things and can export them as CSVs... but I'm not sure if that's going to have any forensic merit (dabbling in forensics for some fun but only just started).

Here is my code below for how I am doing it... but I was wondering if there is a more elegant or 'proper' way of doing it? I haven't used variables or anything yet because I'm not that far into tutorials yet.

Any tips or suggestions on making this more dynamic/robust/efficient would be greatly appreciated too!

```
##Create parent folder for storing retrieved artifacts
$DesktopPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::Desktop)
New-Item -Path "$DesktopPath\Forensics" -ItemType Directory
$parentFolder = "$DesktopPath\Forensics"


##BEGIN SCRIPT:
Write-Host "Beginning extraction"


##SHELLBAGS
Write-Host "Generating ShellBag CSVs"
Function ShellBags {
New-Item -Path C:\Users\User\Desktop\Forensics\Shellbags -ItemType Directory
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU' | 
    Export-Csv -Path "$parentFolder\Shellbags\Shellbags_MRU.csv" -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags' |
     Export-Csv -Path "$parentFolder\Shellbags\Shellbags.csv" -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache'| 
    Export-Csv -Path "$parentFolder\Shellbags\Shellbags_MUIcache.csv" -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
}
ShellBags 


##JUMPLISTS:
Write-Host "Generating JumpLists CSV"
Function JumpLists {
New-Item -Path .\USERS\USER\DESKTOP\Forensics\JumpLists -ItemType Directory
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations' | 
    Export-Csv -Path "$parentFolder\JumpLists\JumpLists.csv" -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
}
JumpLists


##LNKLISTS:
Write-Host "Generating LnkLists CSV" 
Function LNKList {
New-Item -Path .\Users\User\Desktop\Forensics\LNKList -ItemType Directory
Get-ItemProperty -Path C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\|
     Export-Csv -Path "$parentFolder\LNKList\LNKList_Windows.csv" -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
Get-ItemProperty -Path C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office\Recent\ |
     Export-Csv -Path "$parentFolder\LNKList\LNKList_Office.csv" -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
}
LNKList


##LASTLOGON:
Write-Host "Generating LastLogon CSV"
Function LastLogon {
New-Item -Path .\Users\User\Desktop\Forensics\LastLogon -ItemType Directory
Get-LocalUser | Select * | Export-Csv -Path "$parentFolder\LastLogon\LastLogon.csv" -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation 
}
LastLogon
```